# For what parameters $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ is this function continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working on this problem:

For what parameters $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ is this function continuous:

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
a, & x=0 \\
\sin\left(\frac{b}{\left|x\right|}\right), & x \neq 0 \\
\end{cases}$$

I've found an article about $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ function and its limit [here](http://www.math.washington.edu/~conroy/general/sin1overx/), but it left me even more clueless. My first idea to solve this problem was to calculate the left-side and the right-side limit of $\sin(\frac{b}{x})$ as $ x \rightarrow 0$ , and then choose the parameter $a$. But since the limit of this function doesn't exist, that can't be the right approach. What else can I do...?

Comment: The limit just doesn't exist for $b \neq 0$. And thats already the answer I guess (just define $a=\sin(0)$ in that case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a=b=0$ is the only possible choice for continuity on the entire $\mathbb R$(resulting in $f\equiv 0$); all other choices of $a,b$ lead to a discontinuity at $0$ and continuity everywhere else.

Comment: Trivial solutions are so easily overlooked... thanks!

Comment: @Dunno Happy to help. This is when laziness pays off: Always look for a way around the calculations ^^